# MongoDB schema performance optimization

Tags: performance, mongodb

Hello I want to build mongoDB schema with the highest performance.

Generally my question is:

**What is better:
Collection with the huge sub documents array inside(about 10000) or  2 separated collections with the references(one of them may contain 50000000 records)?**

detailed information

I have a mongoDB Model with the complex sub documents.

```
var usersSchema = new Schema({
email:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
packages : [{
    package : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Packages'},
    from : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :'Languages'},
    to : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :'Languages'},
    words : [{
        word: {type: String},
        progress: {type: Number,default : 0}
    }]
}]
});
```

Every user will probably have 3-10 packages with 1000 words. 
Application will probably have >10000 users.
So probably I'll store about 50 000 000 words. 
But I'd love to have Pagination, normal Search and another juicy mongoDB features for collection **words**. But as I know it's pretty hard to use this functions with the sub documents.

My question is: What would be better for the system performance SubDocuments with the invalid pagination, search and update, but divided by users **or** one more independent model with 50 000 000 records ? 
something like this

```
var wordsSchema = new Schema({
      word: {type: String},
      progress: {type: Number,default : 0},
      user : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :'Users'}
  }]
});
```

Comment: That depends mostly on which queries you want to perform. Both schemas are better for some requests but worse for others. It also depends on whether you want to optimize for reads or for writes.

Comment: Than you for your answer. I want to do a lot of read and write operations with the word collection, much less operations with the user collection. Users will change words progress very often. What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is better: Collection with the huge sub documents array inside(about 10000) or 2 separated collections with the references(one of them may contain 50000000 records)?

The first thing that comes to mind here is: why is storing a reference costing you 5000 times what it costs to store in a subdocument?

Okay, looking at your schema I believe the best method is separate collection for words, not packages.

The first red flag I saw is your double nesting here:

```
packages : [{
    package : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Packages'},
    from : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :'Languages'},
    to : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :'Languages'},
    words : [{
        word: {type: String},
        progress: {type: Number,default : 0}
    }]
}]
```

The `words` subdocument will be very hard to work with in the current version of MongoDB, normally 2-3 levels deep starts to have problems, especially with positional operators.

Now considering that you should always work from the highest possible value you can get here:

> Every user will probably have 3-10 packages with 1000 words.

You have also go to consider the cost of housing this document. The operators you need will be in-memory ones such as `$pull`, `$push`, `$addToSet` etc which means your entire document will need to be serialised and loaded into MongoDB's native C++ structs. This will be an extremely consuming task depending on the traffic to those documents.

Considering your comment:

> I want to do a lot of read and write operations with the word collection, much less operations with the user collection.

it merely puts another nail in the coffin of embedding the words within the main user document. Considering what I said in the previous paragraph this will not work well with the cost of using in-memory operators on the `words` array.

> But I'd love to have Pagination, normal Search and another juicy mongoDB features for collection words.

This will work much better if the words are split out, `$slice` is also an in-memory operator and probably would suffer diminished performance here.

And that's a quick reasoned response. I am sure there is more I could explain about my reason but that should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion separated collections is better

**Couple of things Keep in Mind**

1. Max size of single document is 16 MB
2. Don't forget to create index (will improve query performance) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/
3. If you are using MongoDB 3.0 or greater you can use wiredtiger storage engine http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/

Hope it will help

Comment: Don't you think these are general practices? Max size for a single document is 16 MB. For a user and package with above mentioned attributes I don't think it will exceed the doc. size limit. Consider a problem where one user is working with multiple packages and words then your approach suggests cursor/aggregation to get the results which can be very heavy with large no. of documents with indexes. What I meant to say is without knowing proper queries that will used, it is hard to predict the model. Correct me if you have something else in mind.

Comment: @Nachiket - In my first point it self I said keep in mind the max size of doc is 16 MB. so later you are updating your doc there is a good probability of  size exceed 16 MB. I am giving this approach coz i have seen it in real time Cheers - Rohit

Comment: 10000 sub records will easily fit into a subdocument, I am not sure what your answer actually answers other than stating a completely unreasoned single line response

Comment: approximately 99% of the queries will be simple update and read words operations