# Mongo sub-document, good practice or not?

Tags: mongodb

After few months working with Mongo trying to understand if using sub-documents for nested data is good or not, especially in this example:

Assume users collection that each document into it have the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("some valid Object ID"),
    "userName" : "xxxxx",
    "email" : "xxxx@xxxx.xx"
}
```

Now, in my system there are also *rooms* (another collection) and i want to save for each user scores per room.

In my mind, to do that i have 2 major options, (1) create new collection call userScores that will hold: `userId, roomId, scores` fields like i did previously in MySql and other relational DB's (2) create a sub-document into the above user document:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("sdfdfdfdfdf"),
     "userName" : "xxxxx",
     "email" : "xxxx@xxxx.xx",
     "scores": {
          "roomIdX": 50,
          "roomIdY": 50,
          "roomIdZ": 50
     }          
}
```

What do you think is better way so later i can handle searches, aggregations and other data queries via the code (*mongoose* in my case)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion-based. That been said; you should know that  mongodb does'nt support any JOIN operation

Comment: Yes i know, but ODM's support populate operations (i know they're doing 2 queries beyond the sense but it helps and make your code stable) and looks like populate working on 2 collections FK..

Comment: Just have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810204/mongodb-schema-performance-optimization/32811310?noredirect=1#comment53484460_32811310.

Comment: @user3100115 There is nothing opinion based about subdocuments: one-to-few relations work, one-to-many relations are limited by the BSON size limit(and cause frequent expensive document migrations in the mmapv1 storage engine).

Comment: You can find some exhaustive answers about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference